# actions is not being called redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am new to redux. To start it with simplicity, I am trying to display a global state value using Redux.

When tried to see the action object in console, I get "Object {type: "@@redux/INIT"}". What is this ?

Here is my simple code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';

class AllinOne extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>k
        {this.props.globalState}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const store = createStore(myREducer);
store.dispatch(add);

const mapStateToProps = (globalState) => {
  return { globalState: globalState }
}


// Action
const add = () => {
  return {type : 'ADD'}
}

// Reducer
function myREducer(state=0, action) {
  console.log('counter', action) // returns Object {type: "@@redux/INIT"}

  return state;
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps)(AllinOne);
ReactDOM.render(<AllinOne />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action you see is the initialisation of the state. The `add` action should be dispatched afterwards.

There are multiple points that could be leading to your issue:

First, `add` is dispatched before being declared, so maybe you call `dispatch(undefined)` which does nothing. But this is probably just a copy paste issue in your example.

More importantly, `add` is a function when it should be an object. So you should try with:

```
// Action
const add = {type : 'ADD'}
```

Comment: Thanks... One more thing... when I tried to write reducer in ES6 format function:

const myREducer = (state=0, action) => {
...
}

It says: Expected the reducer to be a function. Why ?

Comment: It should work. If it's not once again an ordering issue (variable defined after the moment you use it), then I don't know.

Comment: That's intriguing. If you could set up a jsFiddle or a gist with a working example it would be cool.

Comment: I got it.. the order was the problem. I have put the reducer (with ES6 syntax) above the createStore function call. Thank you so much !!!!

Comment: One more question..my store state value is not being displayed on the browser....using {this.props.globalState} why ?? It shows undefined on console..

Comment: Please post another question with an example and don't hesitate to tag me in the comments. The goal of StackOverflow is to help solve your problem and also help the next people who have the same one, hence why we try to answer only one question per question.

Comment: Hey Cristopher, I tagged you to my new question. Here is the link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304067/global-state-value-is-not-being-displayed-in-redux