# Global state value is not being displayed in redux

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to display a store value on react component. But that returns undefined. My action and reducer are working fine and updating the state.

But component should re-render on every state change. It seems like the mapStateToProps OR connect function is not working correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';

class Sam extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.globalState.no} // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'no' of undefined
        <button onClick={()=>{store.dispatch(incAction)}}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const reducer = (state={name:'Piyush',no:0}, action) => {

  if(action.type==='INC'){
    console.log("INC");
    console.log("getstate => ", store.getState());
    console.log("Old state => ", state);
    console.log("New State => ", Object.assign({}, state, {no:state.no + 1}));
    return Object.assign({}, state, {no:state.no + 1})
  }
  return state;
}

const incAction = {
  type:'INC'
}

const mapStateToProps = (globalState) => {
  return {globalState:globalState.reducer}
}

const store = createStore(reducer);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Sam /></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'))
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Sam)
```

Comment: @ChristopherChiche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `mapStateToProps` is incorrect.  It should be something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (globalState) => {
  return {globalState};
}
```

Since your current `mapStateToProps` simply returns `{globalState: globalState.reducer}`, then when you try to access `this.props.globalState.no` it doesn't exist because `globalState.reducer` doesn't exist.  Your `globalState` looks like `{name:'Piyush',no:0}`.

Comment: I did so, but it did not work. It seems like the mapStateToProps is not being called because any console message inside is also not being displayed in the console.

Comment: To make mapStateToProps work, I did following:

var Cont = connect(mapStateToProps)(Sam);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Cont /></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));

export default Cont;

Now the component also renders but displays undefined store value.